# Kafka: update a key when there is no update in x amount of time

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there a way when using Kafka, to have a key being updated after it has not been seen for x amount of time?

Something like

```
records
    .groupByKey
    .windowedBy(
         TimeWindows
         .of(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
         .grace(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
         .advanceBy(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
    ).count()
    .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(BufferConfig.unbounded())
    ).updateNotSeen(Duration.ofMinutes(30), (k) => (k, 0))
```

So here, Kafka would emit a new record whenever it had not seen a record after 30 minutes. (Done by the hypothetical updateNotSeen.)

In my search I found [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6556) open issue, which, if it would be there, allowed me to do it in some way, but I don't know how I would be doing it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible in the DSL (Java, Scala).

Until such functionality is provided out-of-the-box, you can implement such custom functionality yourself by using the [Processor API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#processor-api) of Kafka Streams, however. (The Processor API can similarly be used to implement custom join operations, for example.). In that case you'd not work with tables--which are a DSL-only abstraction--but with [state stores](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#state-stores) (tables are backed by state stores, fwiw), which support direct read-write access from attached `Processor`s or `Transformer`s. Processors and transformers support [punctuation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#defining-a-stream-processor) to schedule periodic actions, similar to `cron`. During such a scheduled action you could check whether any record, identified by its record key, hasn't seen an update in the past 30 minutes and then act accordingly.

Also, it's very helpful to know that you can [combine the Processor API and the DSL](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#streams-developer-guide-dsl-process) (which you have been using thus far).  That is, you can keep using the DSL for most of your code and only 'plug in' the aforementioned Processors/Transformers (from the Processor API) when and where needed.

Hope this helps!